# Rails/jQuery prevent form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

`jQUery` prevent form submission.

```
 $('#edit_user_form').submit(function(){
        $("textarea[name = user_form_snippet]").enabled = enabled;
        return false;
        e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Below is my rails form.

```
<%form_for @user, :html {:id => "edit_user_form" },
          :url => {action => "update", :id => @user.id} do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

My `jQuery` function is getting called, but for strange reason the form is getting submitted even if use either `return false` or  e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use `e.preventDefault()`, you must have it before your `return` statement, as the `return` is always the last thing that happens in a function.

You should also update your code to include the `e` in the anonymous function, otherwise `e.preventDefault()` doesn't know what `e` is :)

http://jsfiddle.net/UEK7d/ <- Example fiddle